# Centering footer buttons bug with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i've a bug when choosing the tablet layout.
It works like a charm on smartphones and desktop but my buttons aren't centered anymore on tablet.
Here's my code :

```html
  <body>

    <header class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/maison.png" alt="logo" class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 hidden-xs"></a>
      <h1 class="text-center">La maison de l'architecte</h1>
    </header>

    <nav class="">
      <div id="left" class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/city1.jpg" alt="Nos réalisations"></a>
      </div>
      <div id="side1" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/side1.jpg" alt="Nos projets"></a>
      </div>
      <div id="side2" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/side2.jpg" alt="Notre ambition"></a>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <footer class="text-center">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x"></i></a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-flickr fa-2x"></i></a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-spotify fa-2x"></i></a>
    </footer>

  </body>
```

Comment: So what is the bug, and what is your question?

Comment: When i reduce the window to a tablet resolution, the buttons in the footer aren't anymore centered. So my question is : how can they be centered cause it works on desktop and phone resolutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the row class to the nav `<nav class="row">`

see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g74Ep/472/

Comment: Thanks, i just forgot that little class